# Multiple joins or separate queries

Tags: mysql

I have around 16 tables where I need **ALL** the data from them would it be better to do a 16 table join query or split it into 4, 4 table join queries what would you advise?

Comment: If you try Union will it work?

Comment: I'd advise trying them both while running statistics as it depends on several factors like keys, indexes, fill-factors, etc.

Comment: I have tried a 16 table join, all tables have foreign keys and properly assigned unique ids, uniques, and primary keys yet the 16 table join seems to lag alot. You reckon it has anything to do with php putting it all into a single array compared to 4 different arrays?

Comment: Running 4 different queries will not produce the same result with running 1 query. Unless you only need a 16-table Union (and not Join).

Comment: Why don't you post the query here? (and the explain plan)?

Comment: @ypercube will do, got to log into myAdmin hold on

Answer (score 0):

Linear joins, not hierarchical.  Let the database decide.